# Applying a logical function in R Raster

Tags: r, r-raster

I applied a logical function in a single layer raster:

```
f=function(x){if(x<0.4){return(1.88+209.5*x)} else {return(-239.6+810*x)}}
r=calc(x,f)
#where "x" is a single raster
```

After executing, it returns:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (x < 0.4) {:the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (x < 0.4) {:the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

and executes only the former equation. What might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` isn't designed to take a vector of logical conditions. On the other hand, `ifelse` is:

```
f <- function(x) ifelse(x<0.4,1.88+209.5*x,-239.6+810*x)
```

For example:

```
> x <- 0.8*runif(5)
> x
[1] 0.7632327 0.2786816 0.2766365 0.6614716 0.7316004
> f(x)
[1] 378.61851  60.26380  59.83534 296.19197 352.99633
```

You would have to test this to see how it works on rasters.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That also solves a lot of other odd situations I had before.